# Why are liquids deemed hazardous in airport security?

Tags: security

Airports seem to have strict rules for the amount of liquids the passengers are allowed to take on a plane.

Why is that so?

Comment: Expect that your lacking knowledge of *Die Hard 3* is serious, please use common sense before asking trivial questions: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=why+liquid+restrictions+at+airports

Answer (score 5):

It is in part due to the [2006 transatlantic aircraft plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_transatlantic_aircraft_plot), a plan to use explosives disguised as soft drinks to bring down a series of airplanes. As for [how they chose the 3 oz. 1 Liter bag rule:](https://www.nytimes.com/2007/09/11/business/11road.html)

> In an interview, [Mr. Hawley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kip_Hawley) explained that security officials in the
>   United States, Britain and elsewhere quickly determined that the
>   liquids explosion plot was “chillingly real.”
>
> In August 2006, the thwarted terrorists were planning to use “a
>   formulation that was specifically put together to get around our
>   screening measures,”
>
> ...
>
> Tests showed that a container of a certain size is needed for an
>   effective explosion. Separate three-ounce containers limited in number
>   to what will fit inside a single one-quart bag do not have “enough
>   critical diameter” to blow up an aircraft, he said.

This is similar to why you also [now need to put your shoes through the X-Ray Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Reid).